# Deploy a rails app using MySQL to Heroku using ClearDB addon

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, heroku, cleardb

I have a Rails app called "enrollment_app" that initializes and populates all the tables in the database with a MySQL seed file. I built the app, added some migrations and pushed my app to Heroku. However, since Heroku uses Postgres, I need a way to make my MySQL database compatible with Heroku so I am using the ClearDB addon.

When I try to open the app though, I get the message:

```
Application Error
An error occurred in the application and your page could not be served. Please try again in a few moments.

If you are the application owner, check your logs for details.
```

So, I checked the logs and see this error:

```
PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation "enrollments" does not exist
```

I've been following along with this [tutorial](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/cleardb) but apparently I don't know how to make ClearDB look like my local MySQL DB since I'm getting that error above. How can I do the equivalent of `rake db:seed` the MySQL seed file and `rake db:migrate` to the production ClearDB database?

Updated - Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '4.2.1'
gem 'mysql2'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.1.0'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'turbolinks'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0', group: :doc
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.3.5'
gem 'bootswatch-rails'
gem 'ransack'
gem 'jquery-turbolinks'
gem 'kaminari'
gem 'bootstrap-kaminari-views'
gem 'jquery-ui-rails'
gem 'espinita'
gem 'mysqltopostgres', git: "https://github.com/maxlapshin/mysql2postgres.git"

group :development, :test do
  gem 'byebug'
  gem 'web-console', '~> 2.0'
  gem 'spring'
  gem 'rspec-rails'
  gem 'launchy'
  gem 'pry'
  gem 'pry-nav'
  gem 'shoulda-matchers'
  gem 'factory_girl_rails'
  gem 'capybara'
  gem 'newrelic_rpm'
  gem 'poltergeist'
  gem 'database_cleaner'
end

group :production do
  gem 'rails_12factor'
end
```

Comment: `PG::UndefinedTable` is an error from the PG (Postgres) gem. Did you update your Gemfile to use the mysql gem? See this part of the guide: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/cleardb#local-setup

Comment: Yes, I removed the `pg gem` from my gemfile, rebundled, pushed to heroku, and then ran `heroku run rake db:create' but got this error: `LoadError: cannot load such file -- pg`. Then I tried to set the heroku database url to `mysql2` and found this in my heroku logs: `Cannot destroy last attachment to billing app for resource dozing-nimbly-2184`

Comment: Can you post your latest Gemfile?

Comment: @elithrar, here it is. I just added back the 'pg' gem though and it got rid of an error. See my comments in the proposed answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This isn't an issue with ClearDB per se, it looks like you haven't fully divorced from the PostgreSQL defaults. I'd check:

- is `pg` defined in your Gemfile? it shouldn't be. Instead ensure `mysql2` is present.
- Have you installed the Heroku ClearDB add-on for this app, and made it the default database your app will use? Have you uninstalled the Heroku Postgres database? [See here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/cleardb#provisioning-the-add-on) for complete instructions.

Once your Heroku app can connect to the ClearDB database properly, you should be able to set up the database itself with no issues:

```
heroku run rake db:create
heroku run rake db:migrate
heroku run rake db:seed
```

Comment: Thanks for posting, I hadn't deleted my Heroku Postgres database. I did so just now. I then set my new DB through `heroku config:set` and added a "2" after "mysql" since my Gemfile uses mysql2. But when I run `heroku run rake db:create`, I get the error: `LoadError: cannot load such file -- pg`. I'm confused because if I search for "pg" in my project, there are 0 results... So I'm not sure why a pg file is being loaded in the first place. I posted my Gemfile incase that helps.

Comment: Ok so based on some other internet info, I put 'pg' gem back into my Gemfile which got rid of that error. And it actually let me run `heroku run rake db:create` and `heroku run rake db:seed` successfully (I run that before my migrations, which I have to push after seeding). But then when I add the migration files and then run `heroku rake db:migrate`, I get this error: `Mysql2::Error: Table 'heroku_74f570faead6d61.eligibility_states' doesn't exist: ALTER TABLE `eligibility_states``. Do you know why my tables aren't being loaded in the seed file (where they are defined. Works in development.)?

Comment: If you do `heroku pg:status` I have a feeling you have created those in Postgres (given that you added the gem back and it "worked").

Comment: Hm, @BenPritchard I haven't run into that specific error but I strongly thing you shouldn't need the `pg` gem in your Gemfile. Perhaps you can look into the call stack for that error to try to figure out what file is trying to load `pg`? I'd be more comfortable getting that question answered, than I would with leaving an unnecessary gem in just because removing it causes an error; that feels like a recipe for future maintenance nightmares.